# module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__.tracking' has no attribute 'no_automatic_dependency_tracking'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.**internal**.tracking' has no attribute 'no_automatic_dependency_tracking'

Installing dependecies

```
# tensorflow_federated_nightly also bring in tf_nightly, which
# can causes a duplicate tensorboard install, leading to errors.
!pip uninstall --yes tensorboard tb-nightly

!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-federated
!pip install --quiet --upgrade nest-asyncio
!pip install --quiet --upgrade tb-nightly  # or tensorboard, but not both

import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_federated as tff
```

These works fine but errors appear in..

```
import keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator
```

It was working fluently but after runtime get restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Which `TensorFlow` version are you using?
The correct way to import `ImageDataGenerator` api is:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

Comment: It was some dependency conflicts , I resolved by reinstalling `tensorflow`